# Nesting Observables with Angularfire2 (TypeScript)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have the following denormalized Firebase structure:

```
members
  -memberid1
    -threads
       -threadid1: true,
       -threadid3: true
    -username: "Adam"
    ...

threads
  -threadid1
      -author: memberid3
      -quality: 67
      -participants
         -memberid2: true,
         -memberid3: true
      ...
```

And I'm listing `threads` ordered by `quality` in my component:

**featured-threads.component.ts**

```
constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.threads = af.database.list('/threads', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'quality',
            endAt: 10
    }
});
```

Here's an excerpt from my view:

**featured-threads.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let thread of threads | async" class="thread-tile">
...
    {{thread.author}} //Renders memberid3
...
</div>
```

Instead of rendering `memberid3` here, I'd like to get the corresponding member's username property value.

The solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40557579/6024090) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38438622/6024090) both get their observables outside of the constructor, instead of inside as demonstrated in the Angularfire2 [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md#retrieve-data). They use `this.af.database`. When I use the `this` keyword within the constructor, TypeScript warns that it doesn't recognize `af` as a component property (because it obviously isn't). I can use `this` outside of the constructor by declaring the property `af: Angularfire;`, but then I get the console error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined`, which I assume has to do with the fact that declaring the property isn't the same as injecting the `AngularFire` service. I've tried some other things that are probably too comical to be relevant to this question, too.

I'm not entirely sure what's happening here. This problem prevents me from creating a method to which I could simply pass the value of `author` from `threads` as a parameter. This is because methods can't be defined within the constructor, and outside of the constructor `af` is null.

I'm not even entirely sure that this addresses the core question. I want to be able to join/nest these observables any time, not just in this simpler case when I have the benefit of a direct path to the `memberid`. There are a number of questions regarding nesting observables whose solutions don't use Angularfire 2. Unfortunately, I've been unable to translate them to an Angularfire 2 solution.

## Update

I moved all the  logic I had in the component over to a service and now inject the service's method `getFeaturedThreads()` into the component with the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.threads = this.featuredThreadsService.getFeaturedThreads()
    this.threads.subscribe( 
        allThreads => 
            allThreads.forEach(thisThread => {
                this.featuredThreadsService.getUsername(thisThread.author)
                    .subscribe( 
                        username => console.log(username))
            })
    )
}
```

`getUserName()` looks like this:

```
getUsername(memberKey: string) {
    return this.af.database.object('/members/' + memberKey + '/username')
}
```

For now, this logs the `username` property for each `member` to the console. Unfortunately, I only get the key. The values are empty:

[image]

... which is strange to me, given the fact that `getUsername()` is successfully passing the member id's into the query path.

[image]

This is a grab from my Firebase console view that shows the path is correct.

[image]

I recognize the fact that this is a usage question and not an issue with the tech.

Comment: If you want to access the af field outside the constructor, add private before it. `private af: AngularFire`. Now you can do this.af.someMethod

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it like this, I moved it to ngOnInit because you really shouldn't be do it in the constructor. Just add private before your af declaration in your constructor.

```
public ngOnInit() {
    this.threads = this.af.database.list('/threads', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'quality',
            endAt: 10
        }
    }).do(threads => {
        threads.forEach(thread => {
            thread.author = this.af.database.getName(thread.author); //actual method to get the username
        });
    });
}
```

And your component html

```
<div *ngFor="let thread of threads | async" class="thread-tile">
...
    {{thread.author | async}}
...
</div>
```

Comment: I get the typescript warning that `do` property doesn't exit on type `FirebaseListObservable<any[]>`.

Comment: you have to import that operator. 'rxjs/add/operators/do' i think.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you define that method. In order to attach `do` to `this.threads` I had to change the type from FirebaseListObservable to Observable. Since the method isn't a method of `database` I don't see how it gets attached to it. I implemented `this.getUsername(thread.author);` After those adjustments my method returns an object that renders as `[object Object]`.

Comment: FirebaseListObservable inherits from Observable, so do should be available. It's probably rendering as object Object because it has a field on there with he actual username. You'll have to map to that.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but without addressing the question specifically, this answer is incomplete. I'm not sure if the object Object is an empty observable (is that possible?) because when I log thread.author to the console there are no keys or values in the object. I've done some reading on RxJS operators, but haven't been able to figure out the usage of .map to get the values from the field you're talking about--that is, if the observable is even fulfilled.

Comment: Turns out my issue had to do with non-existent database keys. I'm going to accept your answer but I suggest you improve it to demonstrate how you'd actually render the username in the template because as it is your code renders `[object Object]`

Comment: I just assumed your database call would return the actual username string. Not the actual user object.

Comment: This was actually made clear in my database structure at the top of my question. Nor is it atypical to structure two-way relationships this way. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37414449/6024090 Since you haven't edited the solution addrress the specific question it wouldn't be instructive for other users to keep this as the accepted answer.